# Passing argument to script invoked by exec producing undesired result

Tags: bash, shell, unix, quotes

I'm trying to pass an argument to a shell script via **exec**, within another shell script. However, I get an error that the script does not exist in the path - but that is not the case.

```
$ ./run_script.sh 
$ blob has just been executed.
$ ./run_script.sh: line 8: /home/s37syed/blob.sh test: No such file or directory
```

For some reason it's treating the entire execution as one whole absolute path to a script - it isn't reading the string as an argument for **blob.sh**.

Here is the script that is being executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
#run_script.sh
blobPID="$(pgrep "blob.sh")"
if [[ -z "$blobPID" ]]
then
    echo "blob has just been executed."
    #execs as absolute path - carg not read at all
    ( exec "/home/s37syed/blob.sh test" )
    #this works fine, as exepcted
    #( exec "/home/s37syed/blob.sh" )
else
    echo "blob is currently running with pid $blobPID"
    ps $blobPID
fi
```

And the script being invoked by **run_script.sh**, not doing much, just emulating a long process/task:

```
#!/bin/bash
#blob.sh
i=0
carg="$1"
if [[ -z "$carg" ]]
then
    echo "nothing entered"
else
    echo "command line arg entered: $carg"
fi
while [ $i -lt 100000 ];
    do
    echo "blob is currently running" >> test.txt
    let i=i+1
done
```

Here is the version of Bash I'm using:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Any advice/comments/help on why this is happening would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

s37syed

Comment: It looks like you are confusing `exec` with `eval`.

Comment: *Why* are you using `exec` or `eval` here at all? I don't see a legitimate purpose for either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the quoting problem Cyrus pointed out, I'm pretty sure you don't want to use `exec`. What `exec` does is replace the current shell with the command being executed (rather than running the command as a subprocess, as it would without `exec`). Putting parentheses around it makes it execute that section in a subshell, thus effectively cancelling out the effect of `exec`.

As chepner said, you *might* be thinking of the `eval` command, which performs an extra parsing pass before executing the command. But `eval` is a huge bug magnet. It's incredibly easy to use `eval` in unsafe ways (see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)). If you need to construct a command, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for better ways to do it.

Comment: I have deliberately used exec this way - I need to figure out the PID of the process running, and make sure that I don't start blob.sh when it is already running. I have actually come up with an alternate solution where I start the process and save the PID of that new process using $!, and make sure that the process isn't running (if the PID in the file does not exist).

Thank you for this explanation, I will be reading the BashFAQs further.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
exec "/home/s37syed/blob.sh test"
```

(which tries to execute a command named "/home/s37syed/blob.sh test" with no arguments)

by

```
exec /home/s37syed/blob.sh test
```

(which executes "/home/s37/syed/blob.sh" with a single argument "test").

Comment: This does in fact work after verifying. I was under the assumption that I would not be able to retrieve the PID of the "child" script, hence why I executed the command in a sub shell. I appreciate the help Cyrus!